# Convert string to Float or Fixnum

Tags: ruby

Given a string from user input, I want to convert it to a `Fixnum` or `Integer` if the string is a valid int.  I do not want to convert to an int if the string is a float.  If that fails, I then want to try to convert the string to a `Float`.  If the string is not either of these I intend to just raise an exception.

It seems that `String#to_i` just truncates any `Float` value rather than providing any sort of error.  I know I could do some regexing to determine whether a `String` is a valid int, but it seems like there should be some built-in conversion that fails if a `String` has anything other than digits.   Am I missing something?

For example.  I want something like this that fails instead of returning `1`

```
irb(main):092:0> "1.4".to_i
=> 1
irb(main):093:0> "1.4e5".to_i
=> 1
```

Comment: 1.4e5 is a valid number in Ruby - do you specifically want numbers that don't use shorthand?

Comment: @ChrisHeald I want an attempt to convert a float to an int to raise an exception.  I think sawa's answer is what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def int_then_float string
  Integer(string)
rescue ArgumentError
  Float(string)
end
```

Comment: Please, `rescue ArgumentError`, there's really no need to rescue every possible error there.

Answer (score 2):

My solution

```
def typing(value)
  if value.to_i.to_s == value
    value.to_i
  elsif value.to_f.to_s == value
    value.to_f
  else
    value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like rescue so this is my version :)

```
def to_fi(str)
  if str.to_i == str.to_f
    str.to_i
  else
    str.to_f
  end
end

a = "1"
to_fi a
#=> 1

a = "1.0"
to_fi a
#=> 1

a = "1.2"
to_fi a
#=> 1.2
```

Comment: Man, feel free to vote me down but please leave a comment so that I can learn something if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why don't you like rescue? This looks painful to me.

Comment: @DrMavenRebe, rescue is definitely useful but I don't think this is a right case when you can use simple condition. Firstly rescue needs more system resource, secondly in semantic this is not an exception/error at all, why rescue a non-error?

Answer (score -1):

.to_f or .to_f by definition never raise error and if they can't convert the string return 0.
You can use the clases Integer and Float.

this method return the error raised or float number if first can convert to integer

```
def validate_number(string)
   begin
    Integer(string)
    Float(string)
   rescue => e
    e
   end
end
```